# Error in dimnames(x) <- dn : length of 'dimnames' [1] not equal to array extent when i am running logistic.display in R

Tags: r, machine-learning, logistic-regression

I am trying to build a binomial logistic regression model. These are the lines of coded I used. My initial df is approximately 800000 observations. I just used 1000 obs in order to build the model without making it very heavy for R studio to run it. The previous lines were running without any issue. Now that I am trying to apply those lines to my initial df, I don't get the same variables when I run the stepaic method and for the logistic.display function I get the error `"Error in dimnames(x) <- dn :  length of 'dimnames' [1] not equal to array extent"` Can anyone help? thank you

```
library(epiDisplay)
library(caret)
model <- glm(decision ~., data = train.data,family = "binomial")

step.model <- stepAIC(model, direction = "both", 
                      trace = FALSE)

logistic.display(step.model)
```

```
structure(list(id = c(1, 3, 5, 10, 11, 13, 15, 17, 18, 21), 
    var1 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), var2 = c(0.1, 
    0.77, 0.75, 0.09, 0.84, 0.52, 0.45, 0.27, 0.71, 0.15), var3 = c("D", 
    "D", "B", "B", "B", "E", "E", "C", "C", "B"), var4 = c(5L, 
    5L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L), var5 = c(0L, 0L, 2L, 
    0L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L), var6 = c(55L, 55L, 52L, 46L, 
    46L, 38L, 38L, 33L, 33L, 41L), var7 = c(50L, 50L, 50L, 
    50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 68L, 68L, 50L), var8 = c("B12", "B12", 
    "B12", "B13", "B12", "B14", "B12", "B12", "B13", "B12"), 
    var9 = c("Regular", "Regular", "Diesel", "Diesel", "Diesel", 
    "Regular", "Regular", "Diesel", "Diesel", "Diesel"), var10 = c(1217L, 
    1217L, 54L, 76L, 76L, 3003L, 3003L, 137L, 137L, 60L), var11 = c("R82", 
    "R82", "R22", "R72", "R72", "R31", "R31", "R91", "R91", "R52"
    ), decision = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1)), row.names = c(NA, 
10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Hi pipts. You are far more likely to get help here if you make your example _reproducible_. The data you have supplied doesn't even run through `glm` as I explained before. Please supply a data set which allows us to generate a model and which produces the error you have. Posting essentially the same question again won't get you an answer. We're not just ignoring your first question - we _can't_ answer it unless you provide us with data and code that reproduces your error. Please also include the `library` call required to run any non-base R functions like `logistic.display`

Comment: Hi @AllanCameron in my last question i was getting another type of error but when I tried to run the code from the beginning it worked. Now that I tried to do the same to my initial df I'm getting another error while I'm running the ```logistic.display``` function.How can I make a reproducible df? i thought that this is a reproducible format

Comment: The data is in a reproducible format, but running it causes the glm to throw an error because there is only one level in column v8. Either remove this column from the example or include more rows so that v8 has at least two different entries. Then, using this example data frame, start a fresh session and make sure your example produces the error you need help with. That's what we mean by reproducible.

Comment: @AllanCameron i made the changes in the specific column and it produces the same error when I am running the lines of code that I have provided

Comment: Thanks. I started a new session, did `rm(list=ls())` to clear everything in my workspace, stored your example data as `train.data` and ran your exact code. You can see the results below, and I don't get the error you describe.

Comment: @AllanCameron ```df = subset(df, select = -c(id,var1) )```   ```training.samples <- df$decision %>% 
  createDataPartition(p = 0.8, list = FALSE)


train.data  <- df[training.samples, ]
test.data <- df[-training.samples, ]``` could you run those lines first and then run the lines i mentioned in the begining?

Comment: if I store your sample data frame as `df` then run your code I still don't get the error you describe

Comment: @AllanCameron i run the 3 lines of code i mentioned intially, without running the ```df = subset(df, select = -c(id,var1) )``` and it ran, but after i run the subset function i had the error i mentioned. i am trying to understand which line of code leads to this result because i dont think the subset function is able to ruin anyhting in ```logistic.display```

Answer (score 0):

With your current data and code I get the following result:

```r
library(epiDisplay)
library(caret)

model <- glm(decision ~., data = train.data,family = "binomial")

step.model <- stepAIC(model, direction = "both", 
                      trace = FALSE)

logistic.display(step.model)

#> Logistic regression predicting decision 
#>  
#>                   crude OR(95%CI)  adj. OR(95%CI)                P(Wald's test)
#> id (cont. var.)   0.92 (0.7,1.2)   3.85079246964067e+72 (0,Inf)  0.999         
#>                                                                                
#> var2 (cont. var.) 0.23 (0,77.31)   0 (0,Inf)                     0.999         
#>                                                                                
#> var4 (cont. var.) 0 (0,Inf)        0 (0,Inf)                     0.999         
#>                                                                                
#> var6 (cont. var.) 1.1 (0.87,1.38)  7.1846721655706e+38 (0,Inf)   0.999         
#>                                                                                
#>                   P(LR-test)
#> id (cont. var.)   0.014     
#>                             
#> var2 (cont. var.) 0.017     
#>                             
#> var4 (cont. var.) 0.003     
#>                             
#> var6 (cont. var.) 0.017     
#>                             
#> Log-likelihood = 0
#> No. of observations = 10
#> AIC value = 10
```

<sup>Created on 2022-02-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>